# Как в двухколоночном макете растянуть textarea по высоте всех input в соседней колонке?

Tags: html, css, css3

Можно ли как-то с помощью `display: flex` выровнять нормально форму (как на макете)? Просто пытался сам, выровнял три элемента (`input`), а `textarea` тоже влезла под `flex`. В итоге сжалась и всё в одной колонке. Прошу помочь советом)

Скриншот ниже:

[image: место на макете]

Код (только сама форма, не вся страница):

```
 <div class="b-contact"><!--contact -->
      <div class="b-contact_container">
        <h1>CONTACT US</h1>
        <h3>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure. </h3>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="con_name" placeholder="your name">
            <input type="email" name="con_mail" placeholder="your e-mail">
            <input type="text" name="con_sub" placeholder="subject">
            <textarea placeholder="your message">

            </textarea>
        </form>
    </div>
</div><!--contact end -->
```

Стили (опять же фрагмент):

```
.b-contact 
{
height: 676px;
width: 100%;
background: url('../img/contact_bg.jpg');
background-size: 100% 100%;
position: relative;
border-top: 1px #313131 solid;
&_container:extend(.b-wrapper)
{
    form 
    {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: top;
        position: relative;
        top: 254px;
        width: 942px;
        height: 211px;
        border: 1px white solid;
        margin: 0 auto;
        input 
        {
            width: 457px;
            height: 52px;
            margin: 0;
            border: 1px #cccccc solid;
            border-radius: 3px;
            &:not(:nth-of-type(1))
            {
                margin-top: 27px;
            }
        }
        textarea
        {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 457px;
            height: 212px;
            resize: none;
        }
    }
    h1 
    {
        font-family: @montserrat;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        position: absolute;
        top: 111px; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    h3 
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 167px; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: @droid_serif;
        font-style: italic;
        color: #777777;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: я вот хотел поинтересоваться - можно ? для чего в less сначала объявлять переменную а потом эту кучу всего ещё и применять ?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите пример с формой ниже, `flex` он ведь применяется для того, чтобы элементы были резиновые, а у вас зачем-то везде стоят размеры в px, и если вы не планируете делать их резиновыми, то `flex` вообще не нужен.

Ну и `flex-direction` должно быть `row` у родителя, если внутри находятся колонки:

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: top;
  width: 100%;
}
.form-group {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width: 50%;
}
.form-group input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-group textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="con_name" placeholder="your name">
    <input type="email" name="con_mail" placeholder="your e-mail">
    <input type="text" name="con_sub" placeholder="subject">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea placeholder="your message">

    </textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Хм. А другого способа сделать подобное (макет) нету? Без флекса?

Comment: @Андрей, конечно есть и не один, только вам нужно как примере, разделить input'ы и textarea в разные дивы, а дальше можно использовать, например `float:left;`

Comment: Я так думал сделать, но подумал - запись громоздкая весьма. Затем решил искать решение на форумах и сайтах...

Answer (score 1):

Обязательно прочитайте статью "[**Полное руководство по Flexbox**](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/)".

Вот решение:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
form {
  margin-top: 50px; /* Косметика */
  display: flex;
  align-content: stretch; /* Уравняет колонки по высоте */
  justify-content: space-between; /* Прижмет колонки к краям формы */
  width: 100%;
}
.form-group {
  width: 49%; /* Резиновое расстояние между колонками */
}
.form-group input {
  display: block;
  height: 30px; /* Косметика */
  width: 100%;
}
.form-group input + input {
  margin-top: 10px; /* Косметика */
}
.form-group textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* Растянем на все доступное место */
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="con_name" placeholder="your name">
    <input type="email" name="con_mail" placeholder="your e-mail">
    <input type="text" name="con_sub" placeholder="subject">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea placeholder="your message"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```